# Как установить службу Windows из кода?

Tags: c#, wpf, service, update, служба

Для WPF приложения нужно в фоновом режиме проверять, загружать и устанавливать обновления. Решил прибегнуть к службам, но хочу реализовать установку службы из самого приложения, без использования командной строки и утилит .NET Framework. На сайте Microsoft нашел только метод `installutil <yourproject>.exe`, опять же - утилита из .NET Framework. Как можно установить службу из кода?

Comment: Ну используйте командную строку из кода

Comment: Ну это в качестве альтернативы... Есть ли еще способы?

Comment: вы точно хотите руками обеспечивать совместимость с разными версиями и сервиспаками Win и разгребать недокументированные особенности? Не стоит этого делать, есть стандартные механизмы, которые уже учитывают все что необходимо для корректной работы и, хотя бы, относительной совместимости.

Comment: `Для WPF приложения нужно в фоновом режиме проверять обновления.` - [ClickOnce](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/?view=vs-2017)?

Comment: да и в чем смысл службы, почему вы в своем приложении не можете обновление проверить?

Comment: @tym32167, хороший вариант, но обновления проверяются только при запуске. В остальном на 100% согласен.

Comment: @rdorn я думаю, что это XY проблема у автора. Нет смысла проверять обновления, когда прога запущена. А при запуске она сама обновляется. Потому требование в вопросе слегка странное

Comment: Да уж, видимо проблема в моем вопросе, я не дописал, что нужно не только проверять, а еще и загружать и устанавливать обновления, прошу простить. Когда приложение запущено, я не смогу обновить конкретный файл, т.к. он исполняется, для этого мне нужно либо запускать другой софт (апдейтер) отдельно из приложения, либо обратиться к какому-либо фоновому процессу, который работает независимо от приложения (ну почти, приложение его может включить). И уже он может приложение закрыть и спокойно произвести обновление.

Comment: я вот не уверен, что пользователю понравится, если приложение закроется и начнет обновляться. А для обновления при запуске достаточно его опубликовать с помощью ClickOnce. А проверить наличие обновлений и мигнуть об этом пользователю можно и из основного приложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SvcInstaller
{
    class ServiceInstaller
    {

        #region DLLImport
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string lpMachineName, string lpSCDB, int scParameter);
        [DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateService(IntPtr SC_HANDLE, string lpSvcName, string lpDisplayName,
        int dwDesiredAccess, int dwServiceType, int dwStartType, int dwErrorControl, string lpPathName,
        string lpLoadOrderGroup, int lpdwTagId, string lpDependencies, string lpServiceStartName, string lpPassword);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern void CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr SCHANDLE);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern int StartService(IntPtr SVHANDLE, int dwNumServiceArgs, string lpServiceArgVectors);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr SCHANDLE, string lpSvcName, int dwNumServiceArgs);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern int DeleteService(IntPtr SVHANDLE);

        #endregion DLLImport               


        /// <summary>
        /// This method installs and runs the service in the service control manager.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="svcPath">The complete path of the service.</param>
        /// <param name="svcName">Name of the service.</param>
        /// <param name="svcDispName">Display name of the service.</param>
        /// <returns>True if the process went thro successfully. False if there was any error.</returns>
        public static bool InstallService(string svcPath, string svcName, string svcDispName)
        {
            #region Constants declaration.
            int SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE = 0x0002;
            int SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010;
            //int SERVICE_DEMAND_START = 0x00000003;
            int SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL = 0x00000001;
            int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
            int SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG = 0x0001;
            int SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG = 0x0002;
            int SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS = 0x0004;
            int SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS = 0x0008;
            int SERVICE_START = 0x0010;
            int SERVICE_STOP = 0x0020;
            int SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE = 0x0040;
            int SERVICE_INTERROGATE = 0x0080;
            int SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL = 0x0100;
            int SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |
            SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG |
            SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG |
            SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS |
            SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS |
            SERVICE_START |
            SERVICE_STOP |
            SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE |
            SERVICE_INTERROGATE |
            SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL);
            int SERVICE_AUTO_START = 0x00000002;
            #endregion Constants declaration.
            try
            {
                IntPtr sc_handle = OpenSCManager(null, null, SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);
                if (sc_handle.ToInt32() != 0)
                {
                    IntPtr sv_handle = CreateService(sc_handle, svcName, svcDispName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, SERVICE_AUTO_START, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL, svcPath, null, 0, null, null, null);
                    if (sv_handle.ToInt32() == 0)
                    {
                        CloseServiceHandle(sc_handle);
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //now trying to start the service
                        int i = StartService(sv_handle, 0, null);
                        // If the value i is zero, then there was an error starting the service.
                        // note: error may arise if the service is already running or some other problem.
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine("Couldnt start service");
                            return false;
                        }
                        //Console.WriteLine("Success");
                        CloseServiceHandle(sc_handle);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                    //Console.WriteLine("SCM not opened successfully");
                    return false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This method uninstalls the service from the service conrol manager.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="svcName">Name of the service to uninstall.</param>
        public static bool UnInstallService(string svcName)
        {
            int GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
            IntPtr sc_hndl = OpenSCManager(null, null, GENERIC_WRITE);
            if (sc_hndl.ToInt32() != 0)
            {
                int DELETE = 0x10000;
                IntPtr svc_hndl = OpenService(sc_hndl, svcName, DELETE);
                //Console.WriteLine(svc_hndl.ToInt32());
                if (svc_hndl.ToInt32() != 0)
                {
                    int i = DeleteService(svc_hndl);
                    if (i != 0)
                    {
                        CloseServiceHandle(sc_hndl);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CloseServiceHandle(sc_hndl);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }

        static void Test()
        {

            string svcPath;
            string svcName;
            string svcDispName;

            //path to the service that you want to install
            svcPath = @"C:\build\service\Debug\Service.exe";
            svcDispName = "Service Display Name";
            svcName = "Service Name";

            ServiceInstaller.InstallService(svcPath, svcName, svcDispName);            


        }
    }
}
```

Источник: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/installing-a-service-programmatically/